# How to use XmlData attribute in VB

Tags: vb.net, mbunit

I'm running into some challenges with getting the syntax correct for XmlData in VB.

This is OK:

<Test()> _
<XmlData("//data")> _

But I want to add either FilePath or ResourcePath:

<Test()> _
<XmlData("//data", ResourcePath = "Data.xml")> _

<Test()> _
<XmlData("//data", FilePath = "Data.xml")> _

VS displays "Name 'ResourcePath' not declared.

VS Intellisense shows 8 parameters. If I write the XmlData attribute like this:

<Test()> _
<XmlData("//data", , , , "Data.xml", , ,)> _

VS complains 'Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New (ItemPath As String)''

You'll note that in this error message VS shows there is only ONE parameter expected.

However, if you type <XmlData( - VS shows list of EIGHT parameters are expected.

Ed

Comment: Please take the time to better format your question. This will improve the readability, and maximize your chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The VB.NET syntax uses `:=` instead of `=` for attribute properties, so it would be

```
<XmlData("//data", ResourcePath := "Data.xml")>
```